# How to change value of component property in a code in Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have an array of generic child components in my parent component:

```
<component v-for="item in items" :key="item.id" :is="componentName">
```

I can get a child via `this.$refs`, but I can't set a new value for a prop `:is` like:

```
this.$refs[id][0].is = 'MyNewComponentName'
```

How can I set a value of component instance property in a code?

Comment: That's not how props work. If you want to change the value bound to the `is` prop, then change the value of `componentName`, eg `this.componentName = 'MyNewComponentName`. See https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html

Comment: @Phil, But if I will change componentName, so it will be applied to all array items, but I need to apply it only to one instance in this array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First define your prop structure like

```
{
  ...item, // to use your current variables
  componentName: 'MyExistingComponentName'
}
```

Receive the prop and bind it to a data variable, so something like

```
data: function() {
  returns {
     items: this.propItem
  }
}
```

Make the required adjustment in your tag

`<component v-for="item in items" :key="item.id" :is="item.componentName">`

Now you got 2 options, you can either change the `item.componentName` by referencing `this.items` in a method, finding the index and changing it or you could get the parent to change the value of the prop using a custom event using `$.event(event-name`, 'MyNewComponent`). Both methods are fine, it really depends on your requirements.

Refer to https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html
You could also read stackoverflow questions on mutating prop values.

Comment: All components have default name property to define their names to be used as childs. So looks like I don't need to create a new one (componentName).

Comment: Thing is, unless you have a variable bound, you can't dynamically change data. If the componentName property is not in the props or data, there is no way to change it. This way you can handle more complicated scenarios where you have multiple different component names and default values.
Btw you havn't mentioned the error your current solution throws.

Comment: I can't understand how :is="item.componentName" is connected with components I want to render conditionally in your solution. item is just an element in array. It isn't instance of a component.